# React Native: Error in asyc component - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k})

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

In React Native I'd like to have some functions that are consumed by Android/IOS applications. For instance, if an application is installed in the mobile. For this purpose I am using `react-native-shared-group-preferences` library in RN.

I have the issue when running RN project, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR  Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_h, _i, _j, _k}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error is located at:
    in PlatformInfo (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in AwesomeProject(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Following is the snippet of the code:

App.tsx:

```
function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
      </ScrollView>
      <Text style={styles.hello}>Hello, React Native!</Text>
      {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
      <PlatformInfo packageName={'com.facebook.android'} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

PlatformInfo.js:

```
import {Platform, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import SharedGroupPreferences from 'react-native-shared-group-preferences';

const IsInstalled = async (isAndroid, packageName) => {
  if (isAndroid) {
    try {
      const isAppInstalled = await SharedGroupPreferences.isAppInstalledAndroid(
        packageName,
      );
      // IF IS INSTALL
      console.log(`Application is installed: ${isAppInstalled}`);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      // IF IS NOT INSTALL
      // console.log('is not installed...');
      return false;
    }
  }
};

export const PlatformInfo = async ({packageName}) => {
  const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';
  const isAppInstalled = await IsInstalled(isAndroid, packageName);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Operating System: {isAndroid ? 'Android' : 'Iphone'}</Text>
      <Text>
        {' '}
        {packageName}: {isAppInstalled ? 'Not installed' : 'Installed'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The issue is due to returning async PlatformInfo function to App.tsx. However, how could I return the OS and confirmation of installation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `PlatformInfo = async (`   React component's are normally only `sync`, although React Server components can be `async`,  client side that I assume React Native will follow will not.   So what you end up rendering is a `Promise` not a React component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make PlatformInfo not async
2. Use effect hook
3. Within use a self executing async function

```js
export const PlatformInfo = ({packageName}) => {
  const [isAppInstalled,setIsAppInstalled] = React.usestate(false);

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    (async () => {
     const installed = await IsInstalled(isAndroid, packageName);
     setIsAppInstalled(installed)
    })()
  }, [isAndroid, packageName])

  const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Operating System: {isAndroid ? 'Android' : 'Iphone'}</Text>
      <Text>
        {' '}
        {packageName}: {isAppInstalled ? 'Not installed' : 'Installed'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, this did the trick. To accept the answer, could you please add useState(false) and execute useEffect when any of these values change  [isAndroid, packageName] instead of []

Comment: @JohnBarton  `isAndroid` is not a dependency here.